# Send a push to people who don't subscribe to a channel using Parse?

Tags: rest, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm able to send push notifications to mobile clients that subscribe to channels (let's say `channel_1` and `channel_2` using Parse REST API by POSTing a JSON to `https://api.parse.com/1/push`:

```
{
    "channels": ["channel_1", "channel2"],
    "data": { "alert": "Test" }
}
```

However, I'd like to send the notifications to people who subscribe to `channel_1` and `channel_2` but also **don't** subscribe to another specific channel (`channel_3`).

Is there a way to do that with Parse REST API? I know I can do that via Parse's admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on Parse forum, and [someone from Parse responded](https://www.parse.com/questions/send-a-push-to-people-who-dont-subscribe-to-a-channel-using-parse-rest-api):

> In this case, you'll want to use Advanced Targeting. Basically, construct a query over the Installation class that targets objects subscribed to both channels, and don't have the third in the "channels" key.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: YOUR_APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YOUR_REST_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "channels": {"$all": ["channel_1", "channel_2"], "$nin": ["channel_3"]}
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Hello world!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Answer (score 0):

I think advanced targeting is a better fit for what you're trying to achieve 
https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/REST

It is easier to understand the concept looking at the Javascript documentation and then replicate for REST.